# Is there a method to write a power series from a recurrence relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I have found a recurrence relation $C_{n+2} = \frac{(2n-2k)C_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}$
from the differential equation $y'' - 2xy' + 2ky = 0$.

Is there a way to write the recurrence relation in power series from?

I have written out $C_n$ for a few terms such that:

$y = C_0 + C_1x + \left(\frac{-2kC_0}2\right)x^2 + \left(\frac{(2-2k)C_1}{(2\cdot3)}\right)x^3 + \dots$
But I'm not sure how to simplify this to write it in power series form. How would I simplify it for this equation? And in general, is there a go to method I could use to always be able to simplify recurrence relations into summation forms?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4563833/how-do-i-write-a-power-series-from-a-recurrence-relation

Answer (score 1):

If
$C_{n+2} 
= \dfrac{(2n-2k)C_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}
= 2\dfrac{(n-k)C_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$
(assuming I have
translated your recurrence
correctly),
then,
multiplying by
$(n+2)!$
gives
$(n+2)!C_{n+2} 
= 2(n-k)C_nn!
$.

Letting
$a_n
=n!C_n
$,
this is
$a_{n+2}
= 2(n-k)a_n
$
so
$\dfrac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}
= 2(n-k)
$.

For even $n$,
let $n=2m$
and this becomes
$\dfrac{a_{2m+2}}{a_{2m}}
= 2(2m-k)
$.
Multiplying

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{a_{2m}}{a_0}
&=\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}\dfrac{a_{2(j+1)}}{a_{2j}}\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}2(2j-k)\\
&=4^m\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}(j-k/2)\\
&=(-1)^m4^m\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}(\frac{k}{2}-j)\\
&=(-1)^m4^m\dfrac{(k/2)!}{(k/2-m)!}
\qquad\text{(abusing the notation a little)}\\
\end{array}
$

You can play with this somewhat
for the cases
of $k$ even, odd, or other.

You cen do the same
for odd $m$.

I'll leave these considerations
to you.